# Ruby each loop isn't finishing for each element

Tags: ruby, loops, iteration

The following code:

```
# fetch the top 300 podcasts from itunes
itunes_top_300 = Nokogiri.HTML(open("http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppodcasts/limit=25/xml"))

# parse the returned xml with nokogiri
itunes_top_300.xpath('//feed/entry').each do |entry|
  name = entry.xpath("//name").text
  url = entry.xpath("//link/@href").text
  category = entry.xpath("//category/@term").text
  hosts = entry.xpath("//artist").text
  summary = entry.xpath("//summary").text
  artwork = entry.xpath("//image[@height='170']").text
  return name + url
end
```

Is outputting in the view:

> iTunes StoreThis American LifeNPR: Wait Wait... Don't Tell Me! PodcastStuff You Should KnowFreakonomics RadioNPR: Fresh Air PodcastNPR: Car Talk PodcastWNYC's RadiolabDespicable MePearls Before Swine Animated CartoonsThe Moth PodcastAPM: A Prairie Home Companion's News from Lake WobegonHarry Potter Years 1-5 PodcastAce On The HouseTakers - Takers Featurette: Executing the Heist - The Making of TakersNPR: Planet Money PodcastStuff You Missed in History ClassThe Dave Ramsey ShowBook ReviewGlobal NewsVampires Suck ClipsNPR: Science Friday PodcastOther Guys Crash and BurnBack to WorkNPR: All Songs Considered PodcastNPR: Tiny Desk Concerts Podcasthttp://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewTop?id=38&popId=3http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/toppodcasts/limit=25/xml?cc=ushttp://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/this-american-life/id201671138?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/npr-wait-wait-dont-tell-me/id121493804?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/stuff-you-should-know/id278981407?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/freakonomics-radio/id354668519?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/npr-fresh-air-podcast/id214089682?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/npr-car-talk-podcast/id253191823?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/wnycs-radiolab/id152249110?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/despicable-me/id399247154?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/pearls-before-swine-animated/id409382502?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/the-moth-podcast/id275699983?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/apm-a-prairie-home-companions/id215352157?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/harry-potter-years-1-5-podcast/id322144752?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/ace-on-the-house/id414294132?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/takers-takers-featurette-executing/id412910974?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/npr-planet-money-podcast/id290783428?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/stuff-you-missed-in-history/id283605519?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/the-dave-ramsey-show/id77001367?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/book-review/id120315179?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/global-news/id135067274?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/vampires-suck-clips/id405404825?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/npr-science-friday-podcast/id73329284?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/other-guys-crash-and-burn/id407622041?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/back-to-work/id415535037?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/npr-all-songs-considered-podcast/id79687345?uo=2&uo=2http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/npr-tiny-desk-concerts-podcast/id362115318?uo=2&uo=2

You can see that it's getting name for all elements before going on to url.  I want it to evaluate name and then url, etc., for each element before moving on to the next.  What am I doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want it to do for each one?

Comment: @Phrogz: I would presume he wants to print something like "{name} {url} {name} {url}" rather than "{name} {name} ... {name} {url} {url} ... {url}"

Comment: @Anon - yea, that's exactly it.

Comment: sounds like you should post your view code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things causing this problem. First, when you use return inside the each-loop you are actually breaking it so it is only iterated once, not 25 times.

Second, you might not notice that it is only run once because when you use //name in the xpath it returns all names.

Perhaps you could do something like this instead:

```
# Returns top 25 since the url includes limit=25
itunes_top_25 = Nokogiri.XML(open("http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppodcasts/limit=25/xml"))

names_and_urls = itunes_top_25.xpath('//feed/entry').map do |entry|
  name = entry.xpath("./name").text
  url = entry.xpath("./link/@href").text
  category = entry.xpath("./category/@term").text
  hosts = entry.xpath("./artist").text
  summary = entry.xpath("./summary").text
  artwork = entry.xpath("./image[@height='170']").text
  [name, url]
end
```

I changed //name to ./name so that it only returns for the current node. I also changed each to map so that it assigns the variable to an array with all the values returned by the block. And I removed the call to return since it is not necessary.

So this will result in an array of arrays containing names and urls

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is perfect and your explanation was very educational.

Comment: You might change your accepted answer to show parsing XML as XML instead of HTML.

Answer (score 1):

By calling `return` you are stopping your `each` loop on the first iteration. Probably you didn't want that. Further, by using the xpath `//name` inside your loop, you are starting over at the top of the document and finding every name element in the whole document. Hence, when you find the first `<entry>` you then returned an array formed by concatenating the array of every `<name>` element in the document with the array of every `<url>` element in the document.

You probably want either this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
# fetch the top 300 podcasts from itunes
# Use XML instead of HTML
itunes_top_300 = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppodcasts/limit=25/xml"))
itunes_top_300.remove_namespaces!

itunes_top_300.xpath('//entry').each do |entry|
  name = entry.xpath("name").text
  url = entry.xpath("link/@href").text
  puts "#{name}: #{url}"
end
#=> This American Life: http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/this-american-life/id201671138?uo=2&uo=2
#=> NPR: Wait Wait... Don't Tell Me! Podcast: http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/npr-wait-wait-dont-tell-me/id121493804?uo=2&uo=2
#=> Stuff You Should Know: http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/stuff-you-should-know/id278981407?uo=2&uo=2
```

...or perhaps this:

```
# Convert XML entries into an array of hashes
parsed = itunes_top_300.xpath('//entry').map do |entry|
  name = entry.xpath("name").text
  url = entry.xpath("link/@href").text
  { name:name, url:url }
end

require 'pp'
pp parsed[0..3]
#=> [{:name=>"This American Life",
#=>   :url=>"http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/this-american-life/id201671138?uo=2&uo=2"},
#=>  {:name=>"NPR: Wait Wait... Don't Tell Me! Podcast",
#=>   :url=>"http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/npr-wait-wait-dont-tell-me/id121493804?uo=2&uo=2"},
#=>  {:name=>"Stuff You Should Know",
#=>   :url=>"http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/stuff-you-should-know/id278981407?uo=2&uo=2"},
#=>  {:name=>"Freakonomics Radio",
#=>   :url=>"http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/freakonomics-radio/id354668519?uo=2&uo=2"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the variables with the stuff you want then throw it away because you only `return name + url`.

instead try `return name + url + category + thing1 + thing2`

better yet

`return [url,category,thing1,thing2]`

Comment: True, but unrelated to the question being asked.